# Properly delimiting strings in C

Tags: c, concatenation, delimiter

I'm wondering, what would be a good/efficient way to delimit a string that can contain basically any character. so for instance, I need to concatenate n strings that can look like:

```
char *str_1 = "foo; for|* 1.234+\"@!`";
char *str_n = "bar; for|* 1.234+%\"@`";
```

for a final string as:

```
char *str_final = "foo; for|* 1.234+\"@!`bar; for|* 1.234+%\"@`"; // split?
```

Which delimiter could I use to properly split it?

Note that there could be more than 2 string to concatenate.

I'm open for suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because my comments kept getting longer and longer, here is a full answer:

Your `char *` buffer should store the length of the string in the first X bytes (like how Pascal does it). After that length comes the string data, which can contain any characters you like. After that, the next X bytes tell you the length of the *next* string. So on and so forth, until the end, which is delimited by an empty string (i.e. the last X bytes claim that the next string has zero length, and your application takes this as the signal to stop looking for more strings).

One benefit is that you don't need to scan through the string data - finding the next string from the beginning of the first string takes O(1) time, finding how many strings there are in your list takes O(n) time but will still be blazingly fast (if O(n) is unacceptable you can work around this, but I don't think that's worth getting into right now).

Another benefit is that the string data can contain any character you like. This can be a con - if your string might contain the NUL character, you can safely extract it, but you have to be careful not to pass it to a C string function (like `strlen()` or `strcat()`), which will see the NUL character as the end of your data (which it may or may not be). You'll have to rely on `memcpy()` and pointer arithmetic.

The issue is the value of X (the number of bytes you use to store the string length). The easiest would be 1, which would bypass all endianness and alignment issues, but would limit your strings to 255 characters. If this is a limitation you can live with, excellent, but 255 seems a little low to me.

X could be 2 or 4 bytes, but you would need to make sure you have an (unsigned) data type that is at least that many bytes (`stdint.h`'s `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`, or maybe `uint_least16_t` or `uint_least32_t`). A better solution would be to make `X = sizeof(size_t)`, since the `size_t` type is guaranteed to be able to store the length of any string you could want to store.

Having `X > 1` introduces alignment and, if network portability is an issue, endianness. The simplest way to read the first X bytes as a `size_t` variable would be to cast your `char *` data to a `size_t *` and just dereference. However, unless you can guarantee that your `char *` data is aligned properly, this will break on some systems. Even if you do guarantee the alignment of your `char *` data, you'll have to waste a few bytes at the end of most strings to make sure the next string's length value is aligned.

The easiest way to overcome alignment is to manually convert the first `sizeof(size_t)` bytes to a `size_t` value. You'll have to decide if you want the data to be stored little- or big-endian. Most computers will be little-endian natively, but for a manual conversion this won't matter - just pick one. The number 65537 (2 ^ 16 + 2) stored in 4 bytes, big-endian, looks like `{ 0, 1, 0, 2 }`; little-endian, `{ 2, 0, 1, 0 }`.

Once you've decided that (it doesn't matter, pick whichever one you like), you just cast the first X points of data to `unsigned char`s, then to `size_t`, then do a bit-shift by the appropriate exponent to put them in the proper place, then add them all together. In the above examples, 0 would be multiplied by 2 ^ 32, 1 by 2 ^ 16, 0 by 2 ^ 8, and 2 by 2 ^ 0 (or 1), producing 0 + 65536 + 0 + 2 or 65537. There probably will be zero efficiency difference between big- and little-endian if you're doing the manual conversion - I want to point out (again) that the choice is entirely arbitrary as far as I can tell.

Doing a manual conversion avoids alignment issues, *and* completely bypasses concerns about cross-system endianness, so data transferred from a little-endian computer to a big-endian one will be read the same. There is still a potential problem about data being transferred from a system where `sizeof(size_t) == 4` to one where `sizeof(size_t) == 8`. If this is a problem, you can either a) ditch `size_t` and choose an invariant size, or b) encode (a single byte is all you need) the value of `sizeof(size_t)` for the sender as the first byte of data, and have the receiver make any necessary adjustments. Choice a) may be easier, but may cause problems (what if you pick a size too low to account for legacy computers on your network, and as they're phased out you start running out of room to store your data?), so I would prefer choice b) since it scales with whatever system you're running (16-bit, 32-bit, 64-bit, maybe even in the future 128-bit), but that kind of effort may not be necessary for you.

`</vomit>` I leave it to the reader to sort out all that mess I just wrote.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you could encode the length of the string followed by a special character in front of every string?  This way you don't have to worry about what characters are in the next N characters.  It may be a good idea to null terminate each substring as well.

The one advantage of this approach is that you'll be able to parse through the string quite fast.

EDIT:  An even better approach is to use the first 2-4 bytes as suggested by Chris in the comment below instead of an encoded length + special character.

Comment: It's something symilar to pascal strings. A pro of this approach is that it allows strings to contain `'\0'`

Comment: I like the fast parsing too (if null isn't expected to be in the string you can make a list of pointers to the substrings without scanning the whole string)

Comment: You could encode the length in a constant size (like 2 or 4 bytes) to eliminate the special character.

Comment: @Chris that's actually a really good idea.  I like that much more than the special character

Comment: @GWW - I would say use `sizeof(size_t)` bytes for maximum correctness, but that would be platform dependent and if (this may be a big if) the data is being written to a file to be shared with other computers that approach would not be portable (though it would probably work for a while anyway). Using `sizeof(size_t)` is what I would do, but it'd take some extra work to make it properly portable (i.e. the first byte of data in the file encodes the actual value of `sizeof(size_t)` so reading applications could adjust for data from different-sized systems), but it may not be worth it (OP's call).

Comment: (How could I forget this!?) Also, it will be important for portability to decide whether your sizes will be little- or big-endian. You probably shouldn't just cast it to a `short *` and read the integer, because this will create massive portability problems (and potential alignment problems).

Comment: @Martin - Great minds think alike, eh? I just remembered the same thing, but good call beating me by 35 seconds.

Comment: endianess always has to ruin the day :P.  I've seen so many ugly solutions for trying to fix that

Comment: @GWW - It does get a bit hairy, but in the end I suppose I'd say that strings are the one thing Pascal did better than C. String inefficiencies are one of the most annoying things about C programming.

Comment: I like the approach of encoding it, since speed is crucial. Are you guys talking about using a base64_encode()? @Chris: could you elaborate a little bit more about "encoding the length in a constant size" any example?

Comment: I would definitely go with Chris' solution instead of the encoding.  But that could get more complicated depending on how portable you want your code to be.

Comment: @GWW why don't they just extend byte size to kill endianess once and for all? :)

Comment: @GWW: Portability is not critical at this time, however making it portable enough would be a plus :)

Comment: One should note that casting to `short *` or `size_t *` etc. to access an embedded length integer is **undefined behavior**. From a practical perspective, it may break on machines which do not support non-aligned access. Some other issues are that this approach will generate embedded null bytes (but only for certain key sizes) which could lead to bugs that don't get detected right away, and of course the endianness issue. If you want to embed sizes, you **really** need to come up with a clean, well-defined encoding that avoids these issues rather than using quick hacks.

Comment: @R.. It can be easily solved by padding the string to a round length.

Comment: @Darrow11 - Not base64_encode() or anything, just use the first two (or four, or `sizeof(size_t)`) bytes as a number. The simplest way would be to cast the `char *` to an `unsigned short *` (or `unsigned *` or, possibly best of all, `size_t *`). Say you have `char *p = /* data */;` - the length of the data is `*(size_t *)p`, the data starts at `p + sizeof(size_t)` and ends at `p + sizeof(size_t) + *(size_t *)p`. To account for alignment, the next string starts at `p + sizeof(size_t) + *(size_t *)p + sizeof(size_t) - *(size_t *)p % sizeof(size_t)` - it wastes a few bytes, but ensures alignment.

Comment: (Con't) Please note that this relies on `p` being properly aligned as a `size_t` in the first place (guaranteed if you get it straight from `malloc()` but don't count on it any other time), and, as @R.. said, is still ignoring endianness. You can overcome both problems by manually converting the first `sizeof(size_t)` bytes to a `size_t` variable (instead of the cast-and-pray approach above) in an order you decide, so the pointer alignment _and_ endianness become nonissues. You can probably look up how to do that with bit-twiddling hacks, or just use basic arithmetic.

Comment: @Chris: you got me in this one; I understand the point (I think), however, I still don't quite get how would this encode/decode the particular string. Thanks

Comment: @Darrow11 - You tell the length of the string before you start writing the data, so that way you know where the string ends and, logically, where the next one begins. Instead of using a special character to denote the boundaries, you record how long each piece is so you can calculate the boundaries.

Comment: @Chris: is it possible to post a simple sample code? (only w/ 2 strings) cause I'm having hard time getting it. Thanks

Comment: @Darrow11 - Here's how the memory layout would work for a sample, assuming little-endian, 4-byte `size_t`: `{ 5, 0, 0, 0, 'H', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 11, 0, 0, 0, 'S', 'a', 'm', 'p', 'l', 'e', ' ', 't', 'e', 'x', 't', 0, 0, 0, 0 }`. The first 4 bytes decode to a length of 5, which means 5 characters (i.e. "Hello", no nul-termination necessary), then the next 4 characters show a length of 11 (which is "Sample text"), then the last 4 characters are 0, which means a 0 length string (or, in this case, can signify the end of the list). Make sense?

Comment: @Chris:  You should post that as a real answer, I'll definitely vote for it and you deserve the rep!

Comment: @GWW - I did. I may have done more harm than good, though. Maybe I write too much...

Comment: @Chris:  Regardless it's some really good information and you deserve the rep for it!

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use the null character as a delimiter and double null terminate the list.  of strings.  It would look something like this:

```
const char* str_final = "foo; for|* 1.234+\"@!`\0bar; for|* 1.234+%\"@`\0";
                                     delimiter ^             delimiter ^
```

Raymond Chen gave a good overview of the double null terminated string [in a blog post.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/10/08/9904646.aspx)  It's used by several functions in the Windows API.

Answer (score 2):

If you know your strings will always be valid UTF-8 text (or ASCII), you could use a byte that cannot appear in valid UTF-8 (or ASCII) as a delimiter. In UTF-8, bytes C0, C1, F5, F6, F7, F8, F9, FA, FB, FC, FD, FE, and FF are invalid. In ASCII, any byte with the high bit set is invalid.

Comment: FF and FE may appear in Byte Order Mask ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark )

Comment: @pmg: Wrong. `U+FEFF` may appear, but in UTF-8 that does not contain the bytes FE and FF. Its representation in UTF-8 is `EF BB BF`.

Comment: Guess you've never seen a hybrid UTF-8 file :-) But you're right, the bytes **should** never be there.

Comment: A "hybrid UTF-8 file" is not UTF-8. :-) See the first sentence of my answer. Perhaps I should emphasize the word "valid" in there..

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to chose an escape character and a delimiter. Typically the backslash `\` is used as an escape character, but this may lead to confusion as it's already the escape character for string literals. The choice really doesn't matter, let's take the forward slash `/` as escape and the semicolon `;` as delimiter. Ideally chose two characters that are least likely to occur in your strings.

When you concatenate strings, the first step is to search for both characters in the unencoded strings and substitute them by the escaped version:

```
str1 = "foo;bar;baz";
str2 = "foo/bar/baz";
```

becomes

```
estr1 = "foo/;bar/;baz";
estr2 = "foo//bar//baz";
```

Then they are concatenated with the delimiter:

```
res = "foo/;bar/;baz;foo//bar//baz";
```

That's it. Splitting is done by searching for the delimiter *without* a leading escape character and then substituting escaped characters in the single strings back to the unescaped version.

This is a good choice if you want to work with the strings with functions that await a single zero-terminated string, e.g. using the `str` functions or to print them with the `printf` functions. If you can guarantee that only your own functions will work with these strings, then the mentioned delimiting with zeros `\0` is more efficient, especially since you don't really need to split it, you can use a pointer into the full string to use a single partial string from it when using `str` or `printf` functions.

Answer (score 1):

2 ideas:

1) Use standard "escape" approach, something symilar to defining a char* literal in C.

2) Use one `'\0'` character as delimiter, and two of them as end of string marker.